# Ecommerce checkout: when and where to create intermediate and final order for items in cart in relational database

Tags: sql, django, database-design, e-commerce, checkout

I am working on a ecommerce project(in **Django** and it is based on rest API) where users can place orders. Users can add items they are interested to buy in a shopping cart which is persistent. They go through the checkout process to place the order.

I am not clear how to store and manage intermediate order stage before creating final order in order table in case of rest API based service which does not have request session.

I am thinking of these options:

- **using separate cart, order table:** cart table will have items selected by the user. when they click checkout, create an order but with a flag which says it is in intermediate stage. when payment is initiated, it will be marked as a final order.
- **using separate table for cart, checkout and order:** cart table will have items selected by the user. when they click checkout, create a checkout entry. when payment is initiated, create an entry in the order table. here checkout needs to have replica of the order structure. this seems to duplicate lot functionality
- **using cart+checkout(combined), order table:** cart table will have items selected by the user. when they click checkout, checkout stages will be stored in same table. this is similar to the magento sales_flat_quote table. when payment is initiated, a final order entry is created in order table.

I am not clear about the pros and cons for the above ways. What is the standard approach? 
And any references regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it. Antonio Melé has a great approach outlined in his book "[Django 3 By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0868SN6HF)"

They have the book's myshop app [repository](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-3-by-Example/tree/master/Chapter09/myshop) public on Github.

The book outlines having 2 apps (cart, order).

- Order has two models- Order, OrderItems
- Cart doesn't have any model. It saves the added items to the django session. Checkout the carts.py file.

In addition, I personally used a Shipping app to manage variable delivery charges.

Comment: In this case, whenever user is entering checkout but does not complete order will result in many stale orders. How do you address this issue?

Comment: If a user does not complete the order, the items remains in the shopping cart in the sessions.model. You would need to setup an asynchronous task through Celery to clear the sessions.model objects. 
Again, to answer the original question- What is the standard approach? There is no standard approach. It's on the business requirements.

Comment: I understand cart still has the items. But what about order entry created in order table. It will remain. To explain further what if all users enter checkout but do not complete the checkout process resulting in so many entries in order which becomes of no use. Any thoughts about this case

Comment: Cart objects don't hit the order table until payment API gives successful notification :) order table only have objects where payment has been made. You need your `order/views.py` file logic to be in a way that the `order.save()` only occurs after successful creation of payment object.

Comment: i was of the understanding that before redirecting to the payment gateway we create entry in order table. atleast this is how amazon works by experimenting. if this is the case where is the checkout flow data getting persisted, in cart or order? Also i forgot to mention that this is a rest api service.

Comment: You may need to close/update this question or open another question on Stackoverflow.